# jQuery CORS GET is successfull but firebug still displays it in red

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I want to do a cross-domain GET ajax request using jQuery v1.8.3.

Here is my setup:

1. I have a server on `domain1.dev` which issues these CORS headers for *each* requests:

   - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
   - `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
   - `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *`
   - `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`
2. I have a web application on `domain2.dev` which load a javascript from `domain1.dev` called `domain1.js`.

   In this `domain1.js` file, I issue this AJAX request:

   ```
   jQuery.ajax('http://domain1.dev/path', {
       headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
       xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
       },
       statusCode: {
           200: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               // some logic
           },
           401: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               // some other logic
           }
       }
   })
   ```
3. I load the page from `domain2.dev`. The AJAX request is issued (without preflight) and is successfull (status code 200) BUT firebug still displays it in red (chrome says "cancelled") and I don't understand why.

Any idea?

EDIT:

Response headers sent by the `domain1.dev`:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language,    Connection, Cookie, Host, Origin, Referer, User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Cache-Control   private
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Thu, 22 Nov 2012 22:24:44 GMT
Server  nginx/1.2.3
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.6
x-debug-token   50aea62c91ee6
```

while the request headers were:

```
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  obfuscated=uk40mmmqbffues5cpn6omj6mf0; __utma=126865951.1486960365.1353615466.1353615466.1353619027.2; __utmz=126865951.1353615466.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=126865951
Host    domain1.dev:8080
Origin  http://domain2.dev:8080
Referer http://domain2.dev:8080/app_dev.php
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the backend, you must explicitly state which headers and methods you want to allow. The `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers do not support wildcards.

If you want to allow any method / header, just look for the `Access-Control-Request-Methods` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` headers in the (preflight) request, and return the literal value.

And, you cannot use a wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when `withCredentials` is true. Either use the same mechanism as described earlier to simulate the wildcard, or don't use `withCredentials`.

Comment: It's still failing with these settings: 
`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET` and
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Connection, Cookie, Host, Origin, Referer, User-Agent`

Comment: @futurecat The headers must be present in the preflight and actual request. Is this the case?

Comment: @futurecat Updated answer (for simple requests, preflight is optional by the way).